# Decodable: filter items in array that fail to decode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3.2, decodable

How can I ensure that I only filter out Person B below since Person B is the only malformed object?

The documentation for `currentIndex` on `UnkeyedDecodingContainer` states:

> The current decoding index of the container (i.e. the index of the
>   next element to be decoded.) **Incremented after every successful decode
>   call**.

It seems that if you try and filter a decoding failure using `try?`, it never progresses to the next element in the array.

But how would one achieve this? Note that the structure of the JSON cannot be changed.

```
let json = """
{
    "collection" : [
        {
            "name" : "A",
            "surname" : "ob"
        },
        {
            "name" : "B"
        },
        {
            "name" : "C",
            "surname" : "ob"
        },
        {
            "name" : "D",
            "surname" : "ob"
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
}

struct Collection: Decodable {
    let items: [Person]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items = "collection"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        var itemsArr: [Person] = []

        var itemValues = try values.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .items)
        if let count = itemValues.count {
            for val in (0..<count) {
                print("trying \(val) at index: \(itemValues.currentIndex)")
                if let element = try? itemValues.decode(Person.self) {
                    print("adding \(val)")
                    itemsArr.append(element)
                }
            }
        }

        items = itemsArr
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let collection = try decoder.decode(Collection.self, from: json)
print("collection: \(collection)")
```

Produces the output:

```
trying 0 at index: 0
adding 0
trying 1 at index: 1
trying 2 at index: 1
trying 3 at index: 1
collection: Collection(items: [__lldb_expr_101.Person(name: "A", surname: "ob")])
```